# Dynamic 1\2 column table

Tags: html, css

I want to make a site that will control 16 switches through RaspberryPi. I want it to look like this on computers:
|button|some text|button|some text|
and on phones:
|button|some text|
|button|some text|
First I made it as a table and it worked perfectly, but I started to change something and it stopped working. So now i have website that have div table and it work except that it's too long for phones. I would take any idea to make what I want, just to have it over.

Here is my code, with old table as a comment:

```css
html
{
    background-color: darkgrey;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#butTab
{
    border: solid 3px #0000FF;
    margin: auto;
    height: 97vh;
    height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 97);
}
#help
{
}

/*-webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    50% {height: 820px;}
}
*/
.rowM
{
    width: 99%;
}
.but
{
    border: 1px solid #FF00FF;
    float: left;
}
.txt
{
    //border: 1px solid #FF00FF;
    float: right;
    font-family: Calibri;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: right;
    align-items: center;
}
.rowH1
{
    border: solid 3px #0000FF;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.rowH2
{
    border: solid 3px #0000FF;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

@media (min-width: 1100px) {
    #butTab {
        border: solid 3px #0000FF;
        margin: auto;
        width: 80%;
        height: auto;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    .rowM {
        padding: 3px;
        margin: 3px;
        width: 99%;
    }

    .but {
        height: 80px;
        width: 80px;
        float: left;
        padding: 6px 3px 5px 8px;
    }

    .txt {
        width: 85%;
        float: right;
        height: 86px;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: right;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .rowH1 {
        border: solid 3px #0000FF;
        float: left;
        width: 49%;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
    }

    .rowH2 {
        border: solid 3px #0000FF;
        float: right;
        width: 49%;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 800px)
{
    #butTab
    {
        width: 95%;
    }
    .rowM
    {
        margin: 3px;
    }
    .txt
    {
        font-size: 10px;
        width: 80%;
        height: 6vh;
        height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 6);
    }
    .but
    {
        width: 50px;
        height: 6vh;
        height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 6);
        padding: 2px;
    }
    .rowH1
    {
        width: 95%;
        float: left;
    }
    .rowH2
    {
        width: 95%;
        float: left;
    }
}
.button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #3e7327;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #77b55a 5%, #72b352 100%);
    background-color:#77b55a;
    border-radius:10px;
    border:1px solid #4b8f29;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Malinowa Strona</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <script>
        let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?<?php echo time(); ?>" />
</head>
<body>
<form action="main.php" method="post">
    <div id="butTab">
        <div id="help">
        <div class="rowM">
            <div class="rowH1">
                <div class="but"><button ></button></div><div class="txt">Exegi monumentum aere perennius regalique </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rowH2">
                <div class="but"><button ></button></div><div class="txt">Exegi monumentum aere perennius regalique </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowM">
            <div class="rowH1">
                <div class="but"><button ></button></div><div class="txt">Exegi monumentum aere perennius regalique </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rowH2">
                <div class="but"><button ></button></div><div class="txt">Exegi monumentum aere perennius regalique </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowM">
            <div class="rowH1">
                <div class="but"><button ></button></div><div class="txt">Exegi monumentum aere perennius regalique </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rowH2">
                <div class="but"><button ></button></div><div class="txt">Exegi monumentum aere perennius regalique </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowM">
            <div class="rowH1">
                <div class="but"><button ></button></div><div class="txt">Exegi monumentum aere perennius regalique </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rowH2">
                <div class="but"><button ></button></div><div class="txt">Exegi monumentum aere perennius regalique </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowM">
            <div class="rowH1">
                <div class="but"><button ></button></div><div class="txt">Exegi monumentum aere perennius regalique </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rowH2">
                <div class="but"><button ></button></div><div class="txt">Exegi monumentum aere perennius regalique </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowM">
            <div class="rowH1">
                <div class="but"><button ></button></div><div class="txt">Exegi monumentum aere perennius regalique </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rowH2">
                <div class="but"><button ></button></div><div class="txt">Exegi monumentum aere perennius regalique </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowM">
            <div class="rowH1">
                <div class="but"><button ></button></div><div class="txt">Exegi monumentum aere perennius regalique </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rowH2">
                <div class="but"><button ></button></div><div class="txt">Exegi monumentum aere perennius regalique </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowM">
            <div class="rowH1">
                <div class="but"><button ></button></div><div class="txt">Exegi monumentum aere perennius regalique </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rowH2">
                <div class="but"><button ></button></div><div class="txt">Exegi monumentum aere perennius regalique </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My html code:  https://pastebin.com/bMcWRYc7
And my css: https://pastebin.com/H1JPLVFu

Comment: From what I can tell there is a lot of over-complication on your code. Can you share an image what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: It functions as you want it to when the screen <= 800px and screen >= 1100px thanks to the aid of your media queries. It breaks down between 801px and 1099px where your style rule definitions don't quite work with the style you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to achieve: https://pasteboard.co/IL8c35C.jpg

Comment: @tshimkus I dont see it as a problem, I will be happy if this site will have just 2 versions, one for my phone and second for my computer, and that's what I'm trying to do, and because of that I'm not trying to make it as responsive as possible

Comment: It already does that with the code you have provided if the screen is 800px or less. What specifically can we help you with? The only design feedback you provide in the question is "... it's too long for phones"

Comment: When I open this site on my phone, table goes of the screen. I want to get rid of this

Comment: I'd use CSS Grid, but it depends on your browser support requirements

Comment: Do you just want to do `overflow-y: hidden` on `#butTab`?

Comment: I would check CSS grid. I dont know what overflow-y do so no idea uf I want to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used CSS grid and everything works fine.